# Invoking doGet() of servlet before displaying JSP

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Is there a way to call servlet directly from a button in a JSP page? This is however not a POST form submit button. It is just a button which is supposed to invoke `doGet()` method to get some values and forward to another JSP.

This is the servlet:

```
    public class PopulateProjectServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public PopulateProjectServlet() {
    super();

}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {

        List<Project> projects = PopulateProject.getProjects();
        request.setAttribute("projects", projects); 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/UserHome/Projects.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

This is the JSP page with buttons:

```
    </head>
    <body>

     <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="<%MyServletName.Update(request, response);%>"></input>  **<--- I FOUND SOMETHING LIKE THAT BUT DIDNT WORK**
     <a href="/EmployeeLeaveForm/UserHome/Projects.jsp"> <button type=submit action="com.eteration.leavesystem.service.PopulateProjectServlet">Projeler</button></a> 
     <a href="/EmployeeLeaveForm/SharedByAll/Leave.jsp"> <button type=submit>Izin al</button></a> 
     <a href="/EmployeeLeaveForm/SharedByAll/LeaveCancelUpdate.jsp"> <button type=submit>Guncelle/Iptal et</button></a> 
     <a href="/EmployeeLeaveForm/SharedByAll/History.jsp"> <button type=submit>Gecmis</button></a> 
     <a href="/nextpage.jsp"> <button type=submit>cikis</button></a> 


     </body>
   </html>
```

How can I make button goes first to the servlet which in turn forwards to the JSP page?

Comment: Have you heard of ajax?

Comment: The normal flow is servlet -> jsp... not sure what are you trying to do. What flow do you have right now? and what flow are you desiring?

Comment: You must use form action tag to invoke doGet() method of servlet like
<form action="populateProjectServlet"><button type="submit">Projeler</button></form>

this piece of code will invoke your servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you're on Servlet 3.0 already, first put the `@WebServlet` annotation with an URL pattern to let the servlet listen on the specified URL:

```
@WebServlet("/populateProjectServlet")
public class PopulateProjectServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```

Now, the servlet listens on the URL `/populateProjectServlet`.

Then, replace that HTML-invalid `<a><button>`

```html
<a href="/EmployeeLeaveForm/UserHome/Projects.jsp"><button type=submit action="com.eteration.leavesystem.service.PopulateProjectServlet">Projeler</button></a>
```

by a HTML-valid  `<form><button>` wherein the `<form action>` points to the URL of the servlet (please note that the `<form>` method already defaults to GET!):

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/populateProjectServlet"><button type="submit">Projeler</button></form>
```

Use if necessary CSS `display:inline` to display the form inline.

An alternative is to use a link whose `href` points to the URL of the servlet and throw in some CSS to style it look like a button:

```html
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/populateProjectServlet" class="button">Projeler</a>
```

#### See also:

- [HTML tutorials](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I strongly recommend to put that JSP in `/WEB-INF` folder to make the endusers unable to open the JSP page directly without invoking the servlet first.

Comment: I didn't post all codes. I have annotiation at top and other things.. this first invoke my servlet ?

Comment: what does it mean btw ? #{request.contextPath}

Comment: Your HTML was completely wrong. The right HTML is shown in my answer. The `#{request.contextPath}` should have been `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` (sorry, I have JSF in mind, you're still using legacy JSP, I've updated the answer). This prints the context path URL (which is in your case likely `/EmployeeLeaveForm`) so that you don't need to hardcode it. Hardcoding it makes your webapp unportable. But effectively, if you've a `@WebServlet("/foo")`, then it's available on `/EmployeeLeaveForm/foo` and you should point to exactly that URL in `<form action>` or `<a href>`.